# Running meteor app with Docker

Tags: javascript, meteor, docker, dockerfile

I a trying to create a Dockerfile to run and eventually build/run my meteor app. I am using https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteord and my Dockerfile looks like this :

```
FROM meteorhacks/meteord:devbuild
```

which according to how they have everything set up, should be all you need to do. When I run `docker build -t docker/my-app .` 
this is what the output looks like : [image: console log] and I can't figure out what's going wrong or if there is a better way to do this. Also, if anyone has any other ideas how to set up a meteor app for continuous integration (triggering builds and running the build) I am glad to hear what those are (no this is not being hosted in galaxy).